# Is it possible to find an atlas for the set: $\{F:FE = I, E \text{ is a frame for } \mathbb{R}^n\}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, harmonic-analysis, signal-analysis, wavelets

Let $E$ be the matrix whos rows are $ \{e_i^{\top}\}_{i=1}^m$. Let $E$ also be a frame of $m$ elements for $\mathbb{R}^n$, $m \geq n$. This means there exist two constants $A, B > 0$ such that:
$$
A\|x\|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^m |\langle x, e_i \rangle|^2 \leq B\|x\|^2, \text{ } \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$

Frames occur regularly in signal theory and wavelet/Gabor analysis. It can be shown that if a set forms a frame for a finite-dimensional vector space then it spans that space, however, it is not necessarily a linearly independent set.

Corresponding to any frame $E$ is a (generally non-unique) dual frame $F$ consisting of the columns $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^m$ such that
$$
FE = I_n
$$

where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ Identity matrix. I have an optimization problem concerning the duals with a given objective function and this duality condition as the constraint. I would like to know whether this constraint set can be interpreted as a manifold (matrix manifold) with some atlas? i.e., is it possible to construct an atlas for the set
$$
\mathcal{M} = \{F: FE = I_n, E, F \text{ are frames for } \mathbb{R}^n ,E \text{ } \text{ fixed}\}?
$$

Comment: Your set $\mathcal{M}$ is an affine subspace of whatever space of matrices you are working with. You can parametrize it by $M\mapsto F_0+M$ where $F_0$ is a given dual frame and $M$ belongs to the subspace of matrices such that $ME=0$, that is the range of $E$ is contained in the kernel of $M$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. However, will the condition that $F$ is a frame also not have a bearing on this parameterization? The set $\mathcal{M}$ is the intersection of the condition that each of its elements is a frame and is dual to $E$.

Comment: I missed that $F$ should also be a frame. Isn't it an open condition ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by an open condition exactly, but your parametrization seems to work since the sole condition $FE = I$ with appropriate dimensions on the matrices suffices to guarantee that F is a frame. (For a $n \times m$ matrix $F$ to be a frame for $\mathbb{R}^n$, its column should span $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., $F$ should be of rank $n$ which is true given the defining equation for duality).